# Infinite series with binomial summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

If I have an infinite series with first term two and for any other term:
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{4n-2}{4k-1}a_ka_{n-k}$$
What is the general term formula?

Comment: Similar recurrence https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106953/number-of-possible-pr%c3%bcfer-codes. Also on OEIS: https://oeis.org/A008563, from which we can see its generating function solves Riccati equation $y'=y^2+x^2$

Comment: @Sil Thank you for the OEIS reference. If I had used $y=\sum a_n x^{4n-1}/(4n-1)!$, then I would have gotten $y'=y^2+x^2$.

Comment: So, the numbers we see in OEIS A008563 are actually $a_n$ in this question. $2, 80, 38400, 77875200, 449711308800, 5935407169536000, 155268186793574400000$, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n x^n}{(4n-1)!}$. Then by applying $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}$ to the recurrence, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n x^n}{(4n-1)!}(4n-1)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{a_k a_{n-k} x^k x^{n-k}}{(4k-1)!(4(n-k)-1)!}.
$$
The above can be written as
$$
4xy'-y - \frac{a_1 x}2 = y^2.
$$
Applying $a_1=2$, we obtain
$$
4xy'=x+y+y^2.
$$
This is [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4xy%27%3Dx%2By%2By%5E2+).

Following the steps of solving Ricatti equation, the substitution $\frac y{4x}=-\frac{u'}u$ yields 
$$
u''+\frac3{4x} u'+\frac1{16x}u=0.
$$
According to this input in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27%2B3%2F%284x%29+u%27%2B+1%2F%2816x%29+u%3D+0), we obtain the general solution
$$
u=C_1 x^{\frac18}J_{-\frac14} (\frac{\sqrt x}2) + C_2 x^{\frac18} J_{\frac14}(\frac{\sqrt x}2).
$$
This output of Wolfram Alpha can easily be justified by suitable substitutions.

Due to our requirement that $\frac y{4x}$ needs to be analytic at $0$, the second part should not appear. Thus, 
$$
u=C_1 x^{\frac18}J_{-\frac14} (\frac{\sqrt x}2).
$$
Hence, we recover $y$.
$$
y=4x\left( - \frac{ \left( x^{\frac18} J_{-\frac14} ( \frac{\sqrt x}2)\right)'}{x^{\frac18}J_{-\frac14}(\frac{\sqrt x}2)}\right).
$$
Since $J_v'(x)=\frac12 (J_{v-1} (x)- J_{v+1}(x))$, we obtain 
$$
y=\frac{- \frac12 x^{\frac18}J_{-\frac14}(\frac{\sqrt x}2)- \frac12 x^{\frac58}J_{-\frac54}(\frac{\sqrt x}2)+\frac12 x^{\frac58}J_{\frac34}(\frac{\sqrt x}2)}{ x^{\frac18}J_{-\frac14}(\frac{\sqrt x}2)}.
$$
Then the power series expansion of the above solution will yield an expression for $a_n$.

Comment: How can you find the formula to $a_n$ from this equation?

Comment: The simple formula is almost no hope. The J functions have known formulas, then do the division of power series. That is as tar as we can do. Basically, my answer is giving another method of recursively obtaining $a_n$. If there is a simpler expression then we can find a simpler way.

Comment: Thank you any way for the time you have spent on it